# When running `yard server --gems` how can I exclude certain gems? E.g. system default ones?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, yard

I'd like to setup a yard server [Serving Installed Gems](https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/README.md#serving-gems).

Was wondering if there is some way to control which gems are included when the yard server is spun up? I noticed I could specify certain libraries via the `-m` flag... however doing this doesn't seem to include the README.md files?